# How does Mongodb manage hash index collisions?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, hash

I am wondering if mongo handles these collisions by creating a bucket for each key such that a single `O(1)` lookup in the hash index suffices in order to retrieve all documents that have that key.

However, I'm just guessing here as I have found no official information in the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-hashed/#:%7E:text=MongoDB%20hashed%20indexes%20truncate%20floating,2.3%20%2C%202.2%20%2C%20and%202.9%20.).

Does anybody know how mongo handles this? Thank you in advance.